# Python notebook markdown: Bullet points within a coloured note box

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have only just started using alert boxes (colored note boxes in the jupyter markdown cells). These are very useful. However, I am trying to include a bulleted list within the colored box and it does not seem to work. Is there a simple way to do this, or I should just give up?
[Here is some documentation about colored boxes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQNUZ_current/com.ibm.icpdata.doc/dsx/markd-jupyter.html)

For an example, include the code below in a jupyter's markdown cell. The idea is to be able to itemize with bullet points.

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-warning">
<b>Example:</b> These is the content of the box. Here is my list:
- item 1
- item 2
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, once you enter "domain" of html, better stick to html, this will save you a lot of time. Just use

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-warning">
<b>Example:</b> These is the content of the box. Here is my list:
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```